# The new forced-frame-with-white-background causes issues to user avatars that contain transparency

Tags: bug, status-review, design, profile-picture, gravatar

It appears that the new design that has been rolled out recently forces a frame with a white background when displaying the user avatar at the top of the page.

I'm kind of forced to use gravatar to host [my image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/47e98f619e6b1fd3c1162253865b6c3b?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG) because hosting it on stack.imgur will not allow transparency. Here is how my image appears on my User Card, where we can see the transparency being applied:

[image: user card with transparency]

And here is what I see in the top bar:

[image: as seen on the top bar]

This design decision will mess up with all the users that have transparency on their image.

I'd like to point out that it is a discrepancy with all of the other icons that show on the top-bar; none of them (except the user avatar) have a background:

[image: discrepancy with other icons]

And here is what I see on my profile page:

[image: as seen on the profile page]

I feel like the need for adding the white background-and-frame was not needed and causes me to be annoyed every time I look at my top bar now.

Would it be possible to roll-back this forced white frame?

---

- I use Firefox on Windows 10.
- The screenshots are taken on [the site I moderate](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com), but the issue with the top-bar avatar is also visible when using the dark theme on stack overflow.

Comment: Another innocent victim of SE single minded decisions. My condolences.

Comment: Also, FWIW, since they have transparency in their avatar, I'm pretty certain [the Community User](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG) is also annoyed to see how their avatar is displayed on the top bar. (j/k :P)

Comment: Related: [Transparent profile pictures should be rendered on a dark background in dark mode](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399930/4642212). Is the background only in the top bar or also in the user card?

Comment: Another side effect of the white background: there is a brief white flash until the images is loaded